# Rails: Refactoring - json["data"]["counts"]["followed_by"] if json && json["data"] && json["data"]["counts"] && json["data"]["counts"]["followed_by"]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring

Question is pretty much in the title. What's the best way to refactor something like below?

```
json["data"]["counts"]["followed_by"] if json &&  json["data"] && json["data"]["counts"] && json["data"]["counts"]["followed_by"]
```

I want to return `nil` unless `json["data"]["counts"]["followed_by"]` exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [try](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) :

```
json.try(:[], 'data').try(:[], 'counts').try(:[], 'followed_by')
```

Answer (score 1):

I tend towards the [`andand` gem](https://github.com/raganwald/andand) over long `try` chains, e.g.,

```
 json.andand['data'].andand['counts'].andand['followed_by']
```

IMO it just looks nicer.

Comment: 1 point for the andand gem. It definitely looks nicer than using the long `try` chain.